# create photoshop action/droplet with variable output

Tags: batch-file, action, photoshop

I was wondering how to:

create a droplet that saves to a relative filepath.
let's say the droplet is on the desktop in the folder "batches" and this folder also contains the folder "output". Everything that gets dropped will end up in the output folder.

I've noticed that photoshop saves a fixed path to this folder. This renders the droplet useless on any other computer than my own.

Even further pondering:

Is it remotely possible to let photoshop prompt the user once for a destination. This could also be an acceptable solution to the above.

Thanks in advance for any comments,tips,remarks,etc.
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best and simplest way to handle this is to make a working copy of the files you want to transform.  Then when creating the droplet, choose "Save and Close" to overwrite the source files.

The danger of this method is that the user will overwrite source files.  However, this can be remedied by creating a script or Automator action around the photoshop droplet.  It would first copy the files to the destination, then run the droplet.

Comment: I was hoping for something that can't be done aparently. Thanks a bunch for your answer.

Is it me or would a little more possibilities to the actions/droplets make photoshop unreplacable?